# How to create Windows compatible rar sfx archive on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, shell, exe, rar

I want to create a `rar` SFX archive that can be executed on Windows, using Linux. Suppose I want to put in the archive the file `myprog.exe` and automatically execute the file when the archive is extracted.
I've created a init script (`myinit.txt`)

```
;The comment below contains SFX script commands
Path=%TEMP%
Setup=tftpd32.exe
TempMode
Silent=1
Overwrite=1
```

Then I created the archive with the following commands:

```
rar a -sfx archive.exe myprog.exe
rar c archive.exe < myinit.txt
```

Now if I open archive.exe with Winrar I can see my file and all the Option I set correctly. The problem is that if I try to execute the file (with double click) I get an error:

> program too bit to fit in memory

I suppose the problem is that the file doesn't have the layout of a Windows executable.

Searching around I found that `zip` has an option `-A` that can be used to fix this problem. Is there a way to to that with `rar`?

Comment: Found this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1146303) but cannot find *.sfx file on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution! The problem was clearly the `sfx` module. I searched in `WinRAR` program files in my Windows machine and found the Windows `Default.SFX`. I copied that file on my linux machine in the same directory in which I was creating the archive, renaming it to `windows.sfx`. At this point I run:

```
> rar a -sfxwindows.sfx archive.exe myprog.exe
> rar c archive.exe < myinit.txt
```

and it worked!

Just another tip: the file myinit.txt must be written using the Windows newline convention.

Only one thing is still missing: the possibility to set an icon for the archive. Windows documentation show a `-iicon` option that is missing in the linux doc.

Comment: Only `WinRAR.exe` supports switch `-iicon`. Console version `Rar.exe` does not support that switch, whether on Windows nor on any other platform. As I explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24955992/3074564), there are several solutions to create an SFX archive with custom properties. As you can't add an icon on Linux with `rar`, it would be most likely best to replace the icon resource inside `windows.sfx` directly once on Windows and make use of this customized SFX module on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
rar a -sfxdefault.sfx myexeforwindows.exe myprog.exe
```

Comment: I tried but the problem is the same. I tried also `7zr -sfx7zCon.sfx a archive.exe myprog.exe` but no luck.